# $_POST array parsing in PHP

Tags: php, android, post

My android application sends a POST message to server. This message basically contains the types of cuisines selected.

On client side i have something like :

```
ArrayList<String> filterEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<filterEntries.size(); i++){
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filter"+i,filterEntries.get(i)));
 }
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httppost.execute(httppost);
```

However since the value of `index i` could vary from 1 to 8 depending on items selected i need to implement a query so that it shows the name of the restaurants according to the TYPE of cuisines.

Something like this. How can i achieve this effect:

`$query = 'SELECT Name,Short_Loc,Image_Link FROM Restaurant_Info WHERE Type LIKE '"$_POST[filter0]"' OR Type LIKE'"$_POST[filter1]"' ....';`

Comment: $query is just a string. You can build it up the way you want. Just make a loop where with isset() you check if a certain $_POST[] is set and add accordingly. Alternatively your android client could build the query parameters.

Comment: Also never use unsanitized $_POST variables directly in a query ever.  Even if the user isn't setting those variables, really you should be using prepared statements (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) but at least use mysqli_escape_string.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is backwards.

You should be sending all data from your app to your database. Then when you want to pull specific pieces of data, you write an API that does said query, and call that API from your app.

That's what databases are for!

Comment: Actually large portions of my app is mainly web-based. I am not sure how can i implement your idea

Comment: If it's web based, then in your web code, you should be pushing/pulling information from the database as well. It's not an 'idea' this is how databases are used.

Comment: OP is not sending data to his server. He tries to get some data from his server. Nothing wrong with his approach.